google calendar api v3 list returns out-of-range deleted events
I'm querying google calendar api v3 list for events within the last month.  To wit:
"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[censored]@gmail.com/events"
#...
params = {
  timeMin: 1.month.ago.utc.iso8601,
  eventTypes: 'default',
  maxResults: 500,
}

This is returning a pair of events (amongst other responsive data) as follows:
First: a recurring event that started 2022-03-26, ending 2023-03-04 (with status == 'confirmed' and recurrence:
"recurrence"=>["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230304T075959Z;BYDAY=SA"],

).  For future readers, that is more than a year ago, so this should be entirely excluded in 2024 by my query of events in the last month.
Second: a following event as so: an event with the same id with an _R20230304T150000 appended and status = cancelled.
This recurring event is not shown in the google calendar UI.  The UI understands that it has no events that fall within the last month.
1 - I can't find documentation that suggests matching events by looking at id and sorting by an appended _R then date; is this officially supported somewhere?
2 - Do I really have to hand discover cancelled recurring events or am I misusing the API somehow?
3 - the list endpoint (.../events) does not include the ical uuid in the 2nd, ie the cancellation, event.  When querying the cancellation event (.../events/#{id}__R20230304T150000) directly I do see the ical uuid, and it does match the ical uuid of the first event.
3a - am I meant to find any event returned by the list endpoint that doesn't have an ical uuid and issue individual event queries to get its actual data?
How is the return from the list endpoint meant to be used?
Thank you for any suggestions.
